# Multiple folders linking to css files PHP

Tags: php, html, css, directory

I have a PHP file called `header.php` which contains as follows:

```
<title><?php echo $title; ?></title>
<link href="core/css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" /> 
<link href="core/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

When on the root folder of my website it is easy to access these files. Simply using: `include 'header.php'`. However when I am in a directory other than root, for example `order/` the files are not able to be accessed. I can access the PHP file by going back a directory using: `include '../header.php'` however this does not work for the css files included in that file and they cannot be accessed by the file that is not in the root directory.

Can anyone help me with a way to come over this? I like only having one `header.php` file as I can then add/remove files from that document and the change will appear across the whole site.

Many thanks,
Harry

Comment: Simplest way: Start every path with a `/`, then they are relative to the domain root.

Comment: Thanks, I will test this in a second. Okay so If I make all files relative to the domain root then I shouldn't have any issues no matter what directory I make pages in?

Comment: Of course. When you give a relative path, the client has to complete it to a full absolute URL using the current directory and the relative path. When you refer to the domain root by prefixing with `/` however, the current directory does not matter, and all the client has to do is put the protocol and domain in front of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using a universal header it's important to use absolute paths to your css files, from the web root. So if `core` were a folder in the root this would be the revised header.php:

```
<title><?php echo $title; ?></title>
<link href="/core/css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" /> 
<link href="/core/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Notice the `/` at the beginning of the path denoting `from the web root`.

Comment: To be more safe I would generate full path using "http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] . "/core/css/styles.css" in your href

Comment: @castt I don't see how that's any more safe...?